# Wireless headphones not working on 18.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

They successfully connect via bluetooth and when I test the sound from the settings, both sides work. However, when I try to listen to something on the internet (with firefox), I hear nothing.

I tried the solutions to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645009/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-not-working-simultaneously), they didn't work. I also tried using alsamixer - Master is currently set to 100, Headphone to 78, and PCM to 85 - still doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Run `pavucontrol`, if necessary, install it first. When you play something, can you set the output to your BT device on the "output devices" tab?

Comment: @emk2203 I've run `pavucontrol`, the device does show up in the output devices tab, I have the port set to "Headset (plugged in)", and the volume is turned up. I can actually hear system sounds through the headset, I think the problem is with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not a problem with your headphones but the app.

Go to Settings > Sound > Applications > check the sound level for Firefox

Also try other apps like Rhythmbox or something, see if that works. If it does then you've narrowed down the problem specifically to your browser.

Comment: Well the volume for firefox is turned all the way up, but its not playing anything. I realized that it is specific to firefox though because i can hear the sound effect the system makes when I adjust the volume.

Comment: Turn up the volume of whatever you're watching? The Youtube video or whatever? Try different types of sound eg. a Steam store page video and see if you get sound from that.

Comment: did you try `pavucontrol` from @emk2203's comment on your question? I've run into this before and sometimes the Settings application doesn't expose everything you need to patch audio around

Comment: @MikeHardy yes I did, maybe there's a setting in `pavucontrol` that I'm not noticing, but I'm pretty sure the problem is with firefox.

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae script may help you.
But it's not tested on 18.04, please let me know if worked.