# WiFi and Bluetooth fail on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, macbook, 19.10

I just tried a new pair of ear pods connected via Bluetooth to my MacBook Pro (early 2011), where I run Ubuntu 19.10 . The WiFi connection stopped working properly, with about 42% packet loss.

I've tried @Pilot6's suggestion:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

...and @Buried Alive (Here's the link tot he post: [wi-fi and bluetooth not working simultaneously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645009/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-not-working-simultaneously)) (what a nickname), but none of theirs worked.

Anybody else who may know if there is a solution to this?

Here's the output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb:

```
antonio@mclinux:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
Kernel driver in use: tg3
Kernel modules: tg3
02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00d6]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8509 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:0252 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05ac:821a Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

PS: I cant get it connected to another Bluetooth device and have both connection working simultaneously, what might suggest that the problem is with the ear pods, but it works just fine with a Sony Vaio computer, also running Ubuntu 19.10.

Any attempt to help is appreciated.

Cheers,
A

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to link to the 'Buried Alive!' post you mentioned, so we can see what you tried? Not able to find that user name here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command. Usung any solutions makes no sense when you don't know what hardware is there.

Comment: You have a wrong driver installed for Wi-Fi.

Comment: It's curious it works fine basically in all situation, but the one above. I will look into that. Thanks!