# Cant connect to wifi when bluetooth is on

Tags: wireless, 20.04, bluetooth

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and when using my Bluetooth headphones I cant connect to my home wifi, but somehow I can connect to a mobile hotspot, what do you think is causing this problem?

Comment: Bluetooth and WiFi share the same EM spectrum and can interfere with each other. See if changing the channel on your router makes a difference.

Comment: Ideally, a fixed channel, not any autoselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the first two answers, don't know which one fixed it, but now it works

[wi-fi and bluetooth not working simultaneously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645009/wi-fi-and-bluetooth-not-working-simultaneously)